# Run `ls` recursively with wildcards

Tags: linux, bash, ls, wildcards

I'm trying to find all the project files of a particular file type with:

```
ls -ltR *.mb
```

I know there are the files I want in several folders, but I get no results back. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 17):

**`ls` doesn't match patterns**. It simply lists the files or folders in the input arguments. `*.mb` is expanded by the shell *before* passing to `ls`, therefore if there are no files named `*.mb` in the current directory, nothing will be output, otherwise only files in the current directory will be output

The standard way to list files recursively is to use `find`

```
find . -name '*.mb' -type f -printf "%-.22T+ %M %n %-8u %-8g %8s %Tx %.8TX %p\n" | sort | cut -f 2- -d ' '
```

This way you can customize the output list format as you want. See: [List files by last edited date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1405664/995714)

---

An alternative way is to use [`globstar`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) which can be enabled with `shopt -s globstar`

```
ls -ltR **/*.mb
```

The first `**/` will match any arbitrary subdirectory paths. Then `*.mb` with match your files in those directories

> - globstar
>
>   If set, the pattern `**` used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories match.
>
> https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Comment: globstar also works to then remove the files `rm -R **/*.mb`

Comment: @swihart obviously, because globstar is a shell feature and has nothing to do with the commands. The commands only receive a list of expanded files from the shell, as said, they know nothing about the pattern you typed

Answer (score 2):

@phuclv has two good options. When I need to do similar, I typically pipe the output of ls to grep like this:

```
ls -ltR | grep .*\.mb
```

this sends the output of ls to the input of grep instead of outputting to stdout, and grep then outputs only the lines that contain at least one match for the regular expression.

The regex

```
.*\.mb
```

can be explained as:

```
.: match any character
*: preceding character or group should appear 0 or more times
\.mb: literally .mb
```

Comment: This is not really a good alternative to a simple and robust `find . -name "*.mb"` – particularly if you want to do anything with the found files.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Another bug: unquoted `.*\.mb` will undergo globbing. Sole existence of file(s) like `.foo.mb` or `.bar.mb` will change your command in a way you didn't expect.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425). Another bug: `.*\.mb` will match the string `.mb` anywhere in the name instead of only at the end